# Javascript trying to use string.replace() with regex for list value

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to do a specify regex

In php i can do:

```
'/[lg|sm|md|xs]/'
```

Will match or lg, or sm, or md or xs once.

On javascript i can't make it work property.

```
var href = $(this).attr('href');
var t = href.replace('[lg]|[sm]|[md]|[sx]', 'add'); //not working

var t = href.replace('[lg|sm|md|sx]', 'add'); //not working

var t = href.replace('/[lg|sm|md|sx]/', 'add'); //not working

var t = href.replace('/lg|sm|md|sx/', 'add'); //not working
```

For a URL like:

```
href="/img/galeria/lg/duplo-standart/foto1.jpg"
```

All I need is to replace for "lg" on the href and change to "add".

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a regex notation or object so

```
var t = href.replace(/(lg|sm|md|sx)/, 'add');
```

or

```
var t = href.replace(new RegExp('(lg|sm|md|sx)'), 'add');
```

what you are doing is a string replacement, so it will search of a exact string match not a regex match

Comment: Fast and Furious! Thank You.